# How can I verify an exception was thrown with a certain parameter?

Tags: c#, exception

Suppose I have the following exception and method:

```
public MyException(string type)
{
    /* Does soemthing with the parameter */
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    // ...
    if (/* some rule */)
        throw new MyException("A");
    else
    {
        throw new MyException("B");
    }
}
```

I want to test my method, how can I verify using Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework that `MyException` with a specific parameter was thrown? I'd usually go with `[ExpectedException(typeof(MyException)]` but I wouldn't know which of these exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd usually go with `[ExpectedException(typeof(MyException)]`

I suggest you *don't* do that. You haven't told us which unit test framework you're using, but these days most provide something like:

```
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => testSubject.DoSomething());
```

Aside from anything else, that will make sure the exception is only thrown where you expect it to be - not elsewhere.

Next, depending on your framework, you may find that `Assert.Throws` returns the exception thrown, so you can then validate things in that:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<MyException>(...);
Assert.AreEqual("A", exception.Message);
```

Note that testing the exact message is generally pretty brittle - but if it's testing something else about the exception (e.g. `ArgumentException.ParamName`) that's more clear-cut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Moq, it doesn't appear to have `Assert.Throws`. Any similar option?

Comment: @JohnoBoy: Moq is just a mocking library - it's not a unit test library in itself. Surely you're using something else *as well* as Moq, e.g. NUnit, xUnit? If you're not, you should be.

Comment: My bad. I'm using the Visual Studio Unit Testing framework. Missing this functionality might make switch over...

Comment: @JohnoBoy: I'm no fan of VSUT myself, but you could always write your own `Assert.Throws` method (well, `MoreAssert.Throws` or whatever). It wouldn't be hard.